# How to convert string containing {} to array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have string value like below

```
$param = "{{1,0},{1}}";
```

I want to convert above string value to array as similar to below using php

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `strtr` the braces into square brackets and `json_decode`.

Comment: thanks @Amadan, It helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem

```
$param = "{{1,0},{1}}";
$string = str_replace(['{','}'], ['[',']'], $param);
print_r(json_decode($string,true));
```

I replaced all curly braces with square brackets in array and made it in json format to decode it.

Here is your working [demo](https://eval.in/1059705).

Comment: But target string isn't `{[1,0],[1]}`

Comment: @Mohammad I made changes as per that, now OP's exact string in my snippet's input.